# Where Do I get Certificate For Heroku Wildcard Domain?

Tags: heroku, cloudflare, wildcard-subdomain

I am building an app and I want to use a wildcard domain (e.g. `*.domain.com`). In order to add this domain to `Heroku`, I need to obtain a wildcard SSL certificate and import it manually to Heroku. I am using `Cloudflare` as my domain provider. Where can I obtain a wildcard SSL certificate for this purpose, and how do I go about importing it to Heroku?